Implement List<T> of Form, with EventHandler, as an MDI Child
I can't seem to get this working.
It errors at this code:
Window[0].MdiParent = this;

Main Form contains:
static List<frmWindow> Window = new List<frmWindow>();

Window.Add(new frmWindow("windowName", 0));
Window[0].MdiParent = this; // Errors here
Window[0].Show(); // If I omit the above, then it will attempt to show the screen,
// but freeze and not focus (like it freezes in initialization phase)

FrmWindow:
public frmWindow(string name, int id)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Name = name;
    ID = id;
    //lblName.Text = name;
}

There is also an event handler I will need to use on the MDI form. I'm using other forms the exact same way, the only difference is, they aren't in a List<T>. Maybe there is an alternative?
Edit for stack:
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_CreateThreadId()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_MdiParentInternal(Form value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_MdiParent(Form value)
   at Matrix.Client.frmMain.JoinRoom(eventData e) in \frmMain.cs:line 418
   at Matrix.Client.frmMain.Matrix_MatrixToUIEvent(Object sender, eventData e) in \frmMain.cs:line 401
   at Matrix.Client.MatrixHolder.Matrix.ServerToMatrixEvent(Object sender, eventData e) in \Matrix.Client\Matrix.cs:line 214
   at Matrix.Client.Models.ServerModels.ServerModel.Server.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<<_StageTwoReaderServer>b__0>d.MoveNext() in Client\Models\ServerModels\ServerModel.cs:line 223


"Errors here" is not an appropriate problem description.  Show the exception message and stack trace.

MDI forms are nothing new and List has nothing to do with how they're displayed. A static List<frmWindow> Window though can be a problem because it's static and may already contain disposed objects. If you call the question's code twice, the list will contain two forms but your code tries to access the one that was already in the list. At the very least this should be a private instance field, not static.

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_CreateThreadId()
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_MdiParentInternal(Form value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_MdiParent(Form value)
at Matrix.Client.frmMain.JoinRoom(eventData e) in \frmMain.cs:line 418

at Matrix.Client.frmMain.Matrix_MatrixToUIEvent(Object sender, eventData e) in \frmMain.cs:line 401
at Matrix.Client.MatrixHolder.Matrix.ServerToMatrixEvent(Object sender, eventData e) in \Matrix.Client\Matrix.cs:line 214
at Matrix.Client.Models.ServerModels.ServerModel.Server.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<<_StageTwoReaderServer>b__0>d.MoveNext() in Client\Models\ServerModels\ServerModel.cs:line 223

I think your error could be here:
this.IsMdiContainer = true;
this.Text = "MDI Parent";

then in this code:
static List Window = new List();
Window.Add(new frmWindow("windowName", 0));
Window[0].MdiParent = this; // Errors here
Window[0].Show(); // If I omit the above, then it will attempt to show the screen,
// but freeze and not focus (like it freezes in initialization phase)

Perhaps you intend to show the last created window, in that case :
Window.Add(new frmWindow("windowName", 0));
Window[^1].MdiParent = this; // Errors here
Window[^1].Show(); 

not sure what your constructor is doing; perhaps update the answer with more details if this doesn't help
as per your comment, you mention a background thread then perhaps try this:
// Assuming this code is in a Form or Control
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
    {
       Window.Add(new frmWindow("windowName", 0));
       Window[^1].MdiParent = this; // Errors here
       Window[^1].Show();
    }));
}
else
{
    Window.Add(new frmWindow("windowName", 0));
    Window[^1].MdiParent = this; // Errors here
    Window[^1].Show();
}


Sorry this doesn't help,  you are thinking that the main form is not already a MDI Parent form, it is and already has mdi forms working, it's a multi threading issue but doesn't error if it's not in a list

@Josh, then make sure you set the data on the UI thread, see update

Wow, that's interesting.   I was using this invoke below.  I didn't know I could invoke the form like that.
Window.Add(new frmWindow("name", 0));
Window[0].Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate{})); //error here

